# Cannot parse JSON String data to Integer

Tags: json

Suppose my JSON is like this.

```
// {
//   "count": 32,
//   "weight": 1.13,
//   "name": "grape",
//   "isFruit": true
//   "currentPrice" : "30.00"
// }
```

If I read my JSON like this,

```
String current = json.getString("currentPrice");
```

the current variable will have value as "30.00". Is there any way that I can parse this as an Integer? I tried doing Integer.parseInt but It is giving an error like Number format exception for input string "30.00".

I tried removing quotes by applying regex but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `parseFloat()`. `30.00` isn't an integer, even though it's numerically EQUAL to the integer `30`.

If you want it as an integer, you can use `Math.floor()` to convert it to one, or you can use `parseInt()` to get the integer portion, but if you really want the whole value (if it might not always be whole), parse it as a float.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 
`parseInt('current')
parseInt(num); // default way (no radix)
parseInt(num, 10); // parseInt with radix (decimal)
parseFloat(num) // floating point
Number(num); // Number constructor`
to get current

Comment: If I use like **bold**int CurrentPriceNow= Integer.parseInt('newPrice');**bold** It gives me error like invalid charachter constant.